# MySQL trigger take text variable

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

Let's say we got two tables.

First table is **items** - `id, title`. 
Second table is **history** - `id, title, action, user`.

We can have following AFTER INSERT trigger for "This user inserted this item":

```
INSERT INTO history (title, action, user) VALUES (NEW.title, 'INSERT', @phpUserId);
```

---

If I want to insert new item, I can do something like this.

```
SET @phpUserId = 123;
INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES ('My best item');
```

In this case, trigger works perfectly.

**But the problem is**, when I add some text into variable - for example `SET @phpUserId = "library123";` - In this moment the trigger is not able to take that variable.

Any ideas why only integer variables are passed?

Comment: What type of column "user" inside your table "history"?

Comment: @VasylZhuryk varchar 255

Comment: did you try this code? `SET @phpUserId = 'library123';`

Comment: Of course I tried that.

Comment: Please add your trigger to the question together with table definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Good news there's nothing wrong with your trigger and here's the proof

```
drop table if exists i,h;
create table i(id int, title varchar(20));
create table h(id int, title varchar(20), action varchar(20), user varchar(30));

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on i
for each row 
begin
    INSERT INTO h (title, action, user) VALUES (NEW.title, 'INSERT', @phpUserId);
end $$

delimiter ;

SET @phpUserId = 123;
INSERT INTO i (title) VALUES ('My best item');
SET @phpUserId = 'bob123';
INSERT INTO i (title) VALUES ('My worst item');

+------+---------------+--------+--------+
| id   | title         | action | user   |
+------+---------------+--------+--------+
| NULL | My best item  | INSERT | 123    |
| NULL | My worst item | INSERT | bob123 |
+------+---------------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```